# How to create custom filter_by in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to create a slightly more complex `filter_by` - such that if I pass some kwargs and values, and some are `None`, then those aren't included in the filter. I'm not sure how to override `filter_by` globally.

Effectively what I'm looking for is:

```
data = {'is_enabled': True, 'city': 'SF', 'address': None}
query.smart_filter(data)
```

and smart_filter excludes the 'address' field and calls filter_by with 'is_enabled' and 'city' values.

Is there any way I could build something like this?

Answer (score 5):

Subclass `sqlalchemy.orm.Query`, add your `smart_filter` method, and then pass the new class to your `sessionmaker`. Something along those lines:

```
class MyQuery(Query):
    def smart_filter(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs = {key: value for key, value in kwargs.items() 
                  if value is not None}
        return self.filter_by(**kwargs)

Session = sessionmaker(query_cls=MyQuery)
```